# How to escape other codes - php

Tags: php, if-statement, escaping

i have a form with action='#'
that outputting some inputs

and a statement when the submit button clicks

```
if($_POST['edit'] == 'Edit') 
{
    manipulation here
    with printout
}
```

what happen here is the output of the MAIN FORM
and the output of the IF STATEMENT print out when SUBMIT button is click

what i want is, when the SUBMIT button is click, ONLY the PRINTOUT on IF STATEMENT will shows.

Comment: Sounds like you need an `else` for the code that should *not* run in response to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending the if statement with an else - one or the other type of situation?

```
//when form is submitted
if($_POST['edit'] == 'Edit') 
{
    manipulation here
    with printout
}
//when form not submitted
else 
{
    //display form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to display the form after it has been submitted. If that is the case, you can check to see if one of the values submitted by the form is set or not and display the original form based on that.

Here is an example:

```
<?php if( !isset($_POST['edit']) ): ?>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="edit" />
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    Display other information.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yes you understand it correctly, i think that's right too but i already found the easiest code, i used die(); on my if statement. thanks for the help.

Comment: you're gonna run into a lot of troubles if you start thinking that die is a sane alternative to a simple else statement..